# Change default PDF Viewer

Tags: windows, powershell, adobe, gpo

I need to change the default PDF viewer from Edge to Adobe Reader. I should use the logon script or GPO because it's VDI machine (it rollbacks after the start). I've tried to change DefaultAssociations.xml, added string:

```
<Association Identifier=".pdf" ProgID="AcroExch.Document.DC" ApplicationName="Adobe Acrobat Reader DC" />
```

Then I've changed registry in:

```
Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.pdf
```

But these solutions are not working. Does anyone know another solution to fix that?

Windows specifications:
Version: 1803
OS build: 17134.1425

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing default apps in your computers settings? Maybe you can try following the instructions on this Website: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4028161/windows-10-change-default-programs

Comment: I need to automate this process. Well, I need to create a script or GPO (if possible).